# Navigate to another xaml page from Silverlight accordionitem

Tags: silverlight

I am working Silverlight project. I have a page1.xaml and I added accordion control and added a couple of accordionitems inside of the accordion control.  One of items, I added a user control which has a textbox and button. What I want to do is that when users clicks on the button, I want them to navigate to page2.xaml.

I tried following:
in page1.xaml's button handler,

this.content = new page2().

But, what this does is it navigates to page2 inside of page1 within the accordion item (Not the whole page1 navigates to page2).

How can I navigate to page2 from page1 in this case?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-videos/navigation-framework/